# How to fix .c file when header is included but error still persist

Tags: android, c++, cmake, build.gradle

I'm a newbie app developer (android) looking to integrate C/C++ code to my project. I've been stuck on an error message that puzzles me and tried all the suggestions that I could find online.  I can't share all the codes due to confidentiality reasons but I appreciate your support in helping me.

I have two versions of the project, one version has just a single java class, with 5 .h and 4 .c. and 1 .cpp file. This project debugs/compiles fine but when I replicate it into my other project, which is the same except that I have multiple classes and created product flavor for 3 versions of the app, I get the warning.

```
> "warning: implicitly declaring library function 'cabsf' with type
> 'float (_Complex float)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]"  "include
> the header <complex.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for
> 'cabsf'" "undefined reference to `cabsf'"
```

Side note: cabsf is borrowed from the library , not a function that I defined.

I've already added the #include  in the .c file that has the cabsf function but the error still shows up even though I've done so.
This function is predefined in the complex.h library. So I shouldn't have to define it in my program.

What I haven't tried is compiling using a terminal because I used the android studio approach to building a cmake file to help with compilation.

I often see suggestion to add the code "gcc main.c misc.c -o main -lm" but I don't know how or where to put such code in Android Studio.

---

Here's the Cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required  (VERSION 3.4.1) 


add_library( 
        vggsup

        STATIC

        src/main/cpp/c_file1.c
        src/main/cpp/h_file1.h
        src/main/cpp/c_file2.c
        src/main/cpp/h_file2.h
        src/main/cpp/h_file3.h
        src/main/cpp/c_file4.c
        src/main/cpp/c_file5.c
        src/main/cpp/h_file5.h
        src/main/cpp/c_file6.c
        src/main/cpp/h_file6.h
        )

add_library(native-lib 
            SHARED 
            src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)

find_library(
        log-lib
        log)

target_link_libraries( 
        native-lib

        ${log-lib}
          secondtype)

********************************************************
```

Also here's the app gradle:

```
android {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            incremental = false
        }

    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {

        dev {
            dimension "default"
            applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
            versionNameSuffix "-dev" 
            resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName_Dev" 
            resConfigs "en", "xxhdpi"
            externalNativeBuild {

                cmake {
                    cppFlags ""
                }
            }
        }

        mock {
            dimension "default"
            applicationIdSuffix '.mock'
            versionNameSuffix "-mock"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName_Mock"
            externalNativeBuild {

                cmake {
                    cppFlags ""
                }
            }
        }

        prod {
            dimension "default"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName"
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    cppFlags ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
        dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false


        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {

    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
    }
```

I expect everything to debug but I get the error messages. Could this be related to the product flavors? Have I structured my cpp folder incorrectly that it's causing confusion with the product flavors? Any suggestions or leads will be helpful. Thank you for your time

Comment: The core error is about not *including* the headere `complex.h` which declares given function. It is not about the *linking*.

Comment: As you say you should not have to define the cabsf function, so why are you trying to define it?

Comment: My guess is that you need to specify the include directory in your cmake file.

Comment: _"Could this be related to the product flavors?"_ -- this is probably easier for you to answer than anyone else. Make a backup copy of your project, then remove the flavors. Does the problem disappear?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for your reply. I appreciate this. perhaps, I need to concentrate and look into other areas for the problem.

Comment: @john, Thank you for your response. I have not defined the cabsf. I should have made myself clear that I didn't want to follow the instructions given by the error message because it is not correct. It's telling me to include the complex.h file, which I had already done. It was also telling me to define cabsf, which I did not do or want to do because it is already provided in the complex.h file.

Comment: @Luis, this is something that I will try. Thank you!

Comment: @JaMiT I didn't think of it. I'm going crazy with this error to think outside the box! Thank you for this!

Comment: Looks like the problem is related to the minSdkVersion. I had to change it from 16 to 26 and the error went away. Thanks for the help.